# Sample Java or .NET application that uses web services?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I'm setting up an environment and am going to be doing some transactional application performance monitoring.  In my environment, I want to install an application (thick or thin client), that uses web services (i.e. XML over SOAP). I'm having no luck in finding any freeware or something simple.

Does anyone know of any? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are asking here?

Do you just want a pre-built client that accesses a public web service? Or do you want a client that accesses an internal web service (which would imply that the URL needs to be a parameter)?

[XMethods](http://www.xmethods.com/ve2/Directory.po) contains a list of publicly accessible SOAP web services, some of which have clients e.g. [Currency Exchange Rate](http://www.xmethods.net/ve2/ViewListing.po?serviceid=5).

If you have the ability to roll your own, Netbeans has a list of pre configured web services under the Services tab, XMethods has a number of tutorials or there are many examples of code supplied e.g. [A simple SOAP client](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-soapcl/)

Comment: Sorry I should have made myself clearer, updated question... but I think XMethods will work well...